# Divio app docker server connection stuck at "installing"

Tags: docker, divio

I have a problem with my divio app.
setting up my divio application for the first time, I managed to get a check mark for "docker client", "docker compose", "docker machine" and "virtual box" by installing docker toolbox, however, when trying to install "docker server connection" it seems that Divio app gets stuck at "installing" and nothing actually happens. I left it for hours and nothing happened. What am I getting wrong here? Is it permission issues or something else?

P.S. I'm using windows 7 ultimate 64-bit. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We are primarily about programming Q&A. You might need to post your question on our sister site: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Docker](https://www.docker.com), and therefore the [Divio](https://www.divio.com) local development environment, will run natively on Windows 10 Professional and Enterprise.

On other versions (Windows 10 Home, and earlier versions) it cannot run natively and must be run in a virtual machine.

This is why your installation requires Docker Toolbox and VirtualBox. The best way to get past this is to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional, but that's not an option for everyone.

If the Divio app detects that your system does not support Docker natively, it will do its best to install Docker Toolbox and VirtualBox, but this set-up is more complex and fragile, and as you have seen, setting it up can sometimes fail.

Try these steps:

1. Quit the Divio application.
2. Make sure that VirtualBox on your system is fully up-to-date with the latest version. You can download and install it from the [VirtualBox website](https://www.virtualbox.org).
3. Make sure that Docker Toolbox is fully up-to-date with the latest version. You can download and install it from the [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/).
4. Make sure that both applications are able to run if you launch them manually.
5. Ensure that you are running as an administrator user.
6. Check that virtualisation is enabled in your PC's BIOS.
7. Finally, try again with the Divio app.

Comment: It appears there was nothing I could do to make docker work correctly with windows 7. I finally decided to change to ubuntu. So I did. I managed to get past the initial Divio configuration. Now, when I hit setup (for the local server), it remains in "Running command, this might take a while..." phase and nothing actually happens. Any suggestions? @

Comment: @BarsamGh. If you are comfortable with the command line, please follow the steps at http://docs.divio.com/en/latest/introduction/01-installation.html

Comment: @BarsamGh. I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @rvliscano If you create a new question with as much information as possible about your system and any errors, that would be better, unless you are certain that you have exactly the same configuration and errors as the author of this question.